# .Net Core 2 FromSql issue

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

Hello I'm starting to learn how to use .Net Core. I've been trying to get the .FromSql() to work with one of my queries. The issue I'm having is that when the query hits the server @metric is getting set to @metricID=N'"100"' when I set @metricID with query.MetricId. I used the sql profiler to see why I kept getting nothing back and it looks something like this.

```
exec sp_executesql N' select * from metrics where rr.metric_id = @metricID',N'@metricID nvarchar(5)',@metricID=N'"100"'


    public async Task<List<MetricView>> GetMetricAsync(MetricQuery query)
    {
           string qry = @"select * from metrics where metricid = @metricID";
           SqlParameter metricID = new SqlParameter("@metricID", query.MetricId);

        try
        {
            var metricReturn = await _context.Metrics
                .FromSql(qry, metricID).ToListAsync();

             return _mapper.Map<List<MetricView>>(metricReturn);(dropdown);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var t = e.Message;
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            _sqlConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }

   public class MetricQuery
   {
     public string MetricId { get; set; }
     public string MircoRegion { get; set; }
     public string Consortia { get; set; }
     public string Institution { get; set; }
     public string AcademicYear { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: What is the expected query? Should `N'"100"'` be `N'100'`? Check the value for `query.MetricId`. Does it contains extract `"`? If you hardcode the parameter with `SqlParameter metricID = new SqlParameter("@metricID", "100");`, will it have expected query and result?

Comment: @Tao Thanks! You're correct for some reason I wrapper the metricID in double quotes in postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I'm having is that when the query hits the server @metric is getting set to @metricID=N'"100"'

For this issue, it is caused by op adding extra double quotes in postman.

Removing it from postman should resolve this issue.